# flag the repeated values in the column

Tags: python-3.x

I have a table of customers' visits and I need to create new columns that will check if the same customer bought the same car model more than on time (group by 'car_model') the example of the data is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'xx','pr1',2,2,'2011-10-10'],
                   [2,'xx','',2,1,'2010-10-10'],
                   [3,'yy','pr2',3,2,'2014-10-10'],
                   [4,'yy','pr2',3,1,'2013-10-10'],
                   [5,'yy','',3,3,'2015-10-10'],
                   [6,'zz','pr3',1,1,'2009-10-10']
                  
                  ],
                  columns=['ID','Customer_ID','car_model','Total_Visits','Visit_Number','Visit_Date'])
df
```

#### Expected Results:

Create a new column 'Repeated_modle'and the values of this column will be:

1- if the car model is empty or null the value will be "Unknown"

2- if the customer bought the car model once time then it will be "No"

3- if the customer bought the car model more than once time then it will be "Yes"

the result will be like this :
[image]